# Can oneboxing questions/answers use the site's favicon instead of the scaled-down apple-touch-icon?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

I've noticed that when you post a link to a question or answer in chat, and it oneboxes it, it doesn't use the favicon, but instead uses the scaled down apple-touch-icon.

Here're some comparisons, with the favicon on the left and the current apple-touch-icon on the right:

[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]
[image] vs [image]

Besides just looking different, the first two had kind of bad rendering bugs in older versions of Firefox because they had to be downscaled so much:

[image: How they looked in Firefox]

Many of them (but not even all) also have their scale very messed up by all the whitespace surrounding them, which looks bad.

Can you change it?